# MVC 5 redirect from BeginExecuteCore to another controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-5

I try to redirect from function BeginExecuteCore to another controller 
all My controller inheritance the function BeginExecuteCore and I want do some logic if something happen so redirect to "XController"

How to do it?

EDIT:

Balde:
 I use function BeginExecuteCore  I can't use  Controller.RedirectToAction

```
     protected override IAsyncResult BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {


        //logic if true Redirect to Home else .......


        return base.BeginExecuteCore(callback, state);
    }
```

Comment: Although your question lacks details, you can read about Controller.RedirectToAction method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Balde's solution is working but is not optimal.

Let's take an example :

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    protected override IAsyncResult BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
        return base.BeginExecuteCore(callback, state);
    }

    // GET: Test
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // Put a breakpoint under this line
        return View();
    }
}
```

If you run this project you will obviously get the Google main page. But if you look at your IDE you'll note that the code is waiting for you due to the breakpoint.
Why ? Because you redirected the response but didn't stop the flow of ASP.NET MVC and so, it continues the process (by calling the action).

It's not a big issue for a small website but if you forecast to have a lot of visitors, this can become a **serious** performance issue : potentially thousand of requests per second that run for nothing because the response is already gone.

How can you avoid that ? I have a solution (not a pretty one but it does the job) :

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult BeginExecuteCoreActionResult { get; set; }
    protected override IAsyncResult BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        this.BeginExecuteCoreActionResult = this.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
        // or : this.BeginExecuteCoreActionResult = new RedirectResult("http://www.google.com");
        return base.BeginExecuteCore(callback, state);
    }

    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = this.BeginExecuteCoreActionResult;

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }

    // GET: Test
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // Put a breakpoint under this line
        return View();
    }
}
```

You store your redirect results inside a controller member and you execute it when the OnActionExecuting is running !

Comment: Chances are you will receive this kind of error as I do right now with this solution
INET_E_REDIRECT_FAILED

Answer (score 2):

Redirect from Response:

```
Response.Redirect(Url.RouteUrl(new{ controller="controller", action="action"}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Im try write this and success:

```
Response.RedirectToRoute(new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", Params= true });
```